# How to include placeholder text in select_time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an 'hour' field, and would like the UI to display a 'h' inside the field so the use knows what to enter there, however, the 'h' should be aesthetic only, not an actual option that can be selected.

```
<%= f.label :"Select a tour time" %> 
<%= f.time_select :hour, { discard_minute: true, include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control", required: true, placeholder: "h"} %>
```

**Attempt 2**:

```
<%= f.time_select :hour, { discard_minute: true, include_blank: true, placeholder: "h"}, {class: "form-control", required: true} %>
```

**Attempt 3**: `prompt: "h"`, which didn't add the 'h' to the form's aesthetic, but instead as an additional option (that could be selected):

```
<%= f.time_select :hour, { discard_minute: true, include_blank: true, prompt: "h"}, {class: "form-control", required: true } %>
```

[image]

**Attempt 4**: `include_blank: "h"`, but it didn't appear to do anything:

```
<%= f.time_select :hour, { discard_minute: true, include_blank: "h"}, {class: "form-control", required: true } %>
```

#### Desired result

This is the current form:

[image]

I would simply like an 'h' in the right box similar to how there is 'dd/mm/yyyy' in the left box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **method** to generate a **time select** with a custom **prompt**.

```
<%= time_select:name, 'method', prompt: {hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute', second: 'Choose seconds'}  %>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. What worked was `<%= f.time_select :hour, {discard_minute: true, prompt: 'h'}, {class: "form-control", required: true } %>`. In other words, there should be no `include_blank`, and it should have `prompt: 'h'`. It looks like Attempt 3 from the question, but the 'h' cannot be submitted.